# datatable short date format

Tags: vb.net, datetime, datatable

I have a vb.net datatable
the data is entered by the user so no SQL table involved.

When I stored "2/1/2016" into the datatable and spit it back out, it shows up as "2/1/2016 12:00:00 AM"

what would be the best way to format this back to "2/1/2016"

```
Dim table As New DataTable
table.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(DateTime))
table.Rows.Add("2/1/2016")
debug.print (table.rows(0)("Date").tostring)
```

Thanks

Comment: a DateTime always has a Date and a Time.  Use the display mechanism to display the date only

Comment: I tried using getType(Date) but I still get "2/1/2016 12:00:00 AM"

Comment: there will *always* be a time element to the structure.  `Debug.Print(Convert.ToDateTime(table.Rows(0)("Date")).ToShortDateString)`

Comment: Yes That works! thank you

Comment: Things like DGV cells store everything as Object, you have to cast back in order to use the methods associated with the underlying type.  The time portion is still there, you just are not reporting it

Comment: Understood. It just the string representation has been altered to just show only the date portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way I found that works:

```
    Dim table As New DataTable
    table.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(DateTime))
    table.Rows.Add("2/1/2016")
    Debug.Print(CDate(table.Rows(0)("Date").ToString).ToString("d"))
```

User Plutonix also suggest. Which also works! Thank you sir

```
Debug.Print(Convert.ToDateTime(table.Rows(0)("Date")).ToShortDateString)
```

Comment: that will not compile under option strict

Answer (score 0):

```
table.Rows(0)("Date").ToShortDateString()
```

Comment: Huh...not on my PC! (VS2013)

Comment: I got this 'ToShortDateString' is not a member of 'String'. when I try "test".ToShortDateString   in immediate window . This article also suggest ToShortDateString is only for date datatype. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: *Things like DGV cells store everything as Object, you have to cast back in order to use the methods associated with the underlying type.*

Comment: Unless it's handled implicitly because that's how VB works. Right?

Comment: @clweeks *Only* with Option Strict off in which case you are letting the compiler *guess* what you mean.  It is often wrong.  There are 2-3 questions here per week where Option Strict Off is the culprit.  It is not for serious programs...or SO answers

Comment: I know that you personally feel that way. I prefer the flexibility even with the once-in-a-blue-moon hassle it causes me. :-)

Comment: You may feel that there is nothing wrong with leaving `Option Strict Off` and you may believe that it's OK to post answers that require it. However, you should at least warn readers if code that you post will **only** work with `Option Strict Off`.

Comment: Yeah, totally. That was something we worked out in the thread of comments. I'm so unused to all the extra code that having Option Strict set to on entails that I first didn't realize what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

to covert it to "MM/dd/yyyy"

```
CType(table.Rows(0)("Date").ToString, Date).ToShortDateString
```